# Change ASP.NET Core RC2 application architecture to x86

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I need to set application architecture to x86. By default in my case it uses x64.

There is no such property in project settings.

I tried to change it using configuration manager, but can't add x86.

In RC1 we had command: dnvm list, which was used to check installed versions, but dotnet does not have such option.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the "platform" value in "buildOptions" in your project.json file to "x86", although there seems to be an issue with getting this to work correctly. See [Asp.Net project with Build platform x86](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3091) for the discussion surrounding this.

[image]

Comment: After looking at GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3091) and issues it refers to I can conclude that platform flags are not respected by dotnet tooling yet. I'm running SDK 1.0.0-preview2-003133 and the problem is still there.